# DataBound WPF ListBox Styling on ListBoxItems

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles, databound

I have a `ListBox` that during development I had the items in the `ListBox` hardcoded and styled. This is how the items were styled.

```
<ComboBoxItem Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Content="ComboBoxItem" >
    <ComboBoxItem.Foreground>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6F6F6F" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFD1D1D1" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ComboBoxItem.Foreground>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

But when I set the `ItemsSource` property to a data object, It said my xaml was invalid. Presumably because it was adding an item through XAML.

How can I create the `Style` for each item, as noted in the above XAML, once you have it bound to a datasource?

Thanks.

Comment: This should work.  Something else is wrong.  The exact error message would help.

Comment: This would not necessarily work when bound to a list of items. The XAML shown only would style the current ComboBoxItem. Each databound item would have its own ComboBoxItem, thus you would need to use styles as I describe in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Styles:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6F6F6F" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFD1D1D1" Offset="1"/>
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Hope this helps!